# large form or javascript locks up browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blocking

I have a html form with about 105 fields, which includes some javascript activity:

1) expand/collapse sections

http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html

2) date picker

3) AutoSave functionality

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function counter() {
    email = document.getElementById("applicant-email").value;
        if (email.match(emregex) || cd == cdLength){
            if (email.match(emregex)){
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = left + cd-- + right + button;
            if (cd < 0){
                formAutosave();
            }
            }else{
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Enter your email address for AutoSave <a onclick=\"javascript:alert(\'Please enter an email address\');\"><span><b></b>Save Now</span></a>";
            }
        }
    };
    function formAutosave() {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    email = document.getElementById("applicant-email").value;
        if (email.match(emregex)){
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = \'<a><span><b></b>Saving ...</span></a>\';
            var values = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < userForm.length; i++) {
        if (userForm.elements[i].value != null) {
            if (userForm.elements[i].name == "form[autosave]") {
            userForm.elements[i].value = "TRUE";
                    }
                    if (userForm.elements[i].id == "'.$fieldId.'"){
            userForm.elements[i].value = email;
        }
        if (userForm.elements[i].id != "finished"){
            values += userForm.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURI(userForm.elements[i].value) + "&";
                    }
            }
        }
            values = values.substring(0, values.length - 1);
            jQuery.post(                 
                "http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].
                    $uri.strstr($uri,'?')?'&':'?').'autosave=1&format=raw",
        values,
        function (submissionId){
            if (parseInt(submissionId) > 0){
                jQuery("#continue").val(parseInt(submissionId));
            }
                        cd = cdLength;
            timer = window.setInterval("counter()", 1000);
                    }
                );
            };
        };

    var userForm = document.getElementById("userForm");
        var emregex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        cdLength = '.self::SAVEINTERVAL.';

    var left = \'Automatically saving in \';
    var cd = cdLength;
    var right = \' seconds or \';
    var button = \'<a onclick="javascript: formAutosave();"><span><b></b>Save Now</span></a>\';

        jQuery("#applicant-email").val(jQuery("#'.$fieldId.'").val());
    var timer = window.setInterval("counter()", 1000);
```

';

We have recorded 3 testing videos (Chrome, Firefox, IE9), in all of which there is a visible slowdown using dropdowns in the form, even though the user has not used expand/collapse or date picker. SO I'm expecting that we are causing a lock up or memory leak in the auto save routine.

Advice on refactoring would be appreciated.

Comment: God kills a kitten every time you pass a string to `setInterval()`.

Comment: Any reason this is half core-javascript and half-jQuery?

Comment: You can start by reducing your DOM lookups. If the number of elements on the form is static once the page is loaded then add a "var formElements = userForm.elements;" right up front and use that to loop through instead.

Comment: @mike we're still learning, is there core jquery interval handling you can point me to?

Comment: @adam, thanks will implement and get back to here

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are great and I'd recommended following the advice posted by @Adam and @Alex (pass a named function instead).  Also, you might try implementing a bit differently (i.e. the Module design pattern or some other best practices).  Take a look at this StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840420/recommended-javascript-annotated-source-code-for-learning